# Android Studio for Project Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

I have downloaded latest Android Studio 2.2.3 and I want to start with C examples for project Tango phone (Lenovo Phab 2 Pro) using C API. The phone itself says it's run Android 6.0.1, kernel 3.10.84 on device.

Google developer documentation for Tango Project suggest to install Android Studio with Android SDK 24.4.1, Platform tools 23.1 and NDK 11.0.0.

By installing latest Android Studio there is no offering to install those versions of tools. Is it possible to use whatever SDK for development (latest)?

Where do I find aforementioned versions?

What Android SDK & NDK version is required for phone which run Android 6.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

I started using the Dev Kit which runs Android 4.4 KitKat and I just recently got the Phab 2 Pro this week and I didn't need to make any updates to my Android Studio SDK manager.

Since I am working only with the Tango and not with the underlying Android features, I have found no need to require 6.0 for I am not using any of the extra features.

Also go [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c) and clone the repo and run the hello-world and see if you can get it to work on your phone, if so you are good to go!

[image: My Android Studio]

Comment: Cool, just I am not using DevKit wih KitKat but I want to use real phone (Lenovo Phab 2 Pro) with android  6.0.1 marshmallow.

Comment: Well then you can use any SDK from 4.4 to 6 as versions are backward compatible. The real idea behind the versions is if you are using a feature that is only for Marshmallow and up. 

As for NDK, Vulkan is really new and only requires version 12 so what ever is new right now (should be 13 something) will work

Answer (score -1):

the SDK Manager which is part of Android Studio offers you choices on levels of android builds like 4.4.2/5.1/6.0/6.1, etc. Platform tools package is a module within the SDK Manager which also has levels which are based on the android build. The NDK is a completely different package and depending on what you want to accomplish you might be able to not worry about it to start of with. install Android Studio and then setup the SDK Manager to cover what devices you want to build for. get the latest Platform tools package setup and you will be ready to code. once you start setting up your environment things will fall in place. for the most part the installer does the work. pay attention to the things needed prior to installing Android Studio. i think you need to install a jdk and set paths and variables.

Comment: What should I install to develop for 6.0.1 Android?

Comment: android studio with api level of 6.0.1 [23] included.

Comment: there are so many *android* version of tools, SDKs, platforms - seems too me quite mess around android development and still not able to build simple app as suggested "hello world"

Comment: android development has a very steep learning curve, in my opinion. but, google does a good job in presenting examples in multiple languages for tango programming. look for the examples on github, the community is growing and very helpful. membership on tango's google+ site was ~4,000 this time last year. close to 12,000 now. but, yeah, one must be very dedicated to develop for the tango device.

Comment: i got compiled examples "cpp_basic_examples" from https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c but still studying "how it works". Why is there Tango C API and Tango Java API as well? It seems that both API do almost the same. Any benefit one over other and vice versa?

Comment: those examples are designed to show how each language API works. they also provide a unity interface and have examples for that. i have read that the c API is best for the math if you plan on using a lot of your own coding for the control/manipulation of the point clouds. i found it rather easy for my purposes to stay in unity since most all the details are handled by unity, i did not have to write specific  code because the unity environment provided what i wanted.